# Iterate function using apply for similar column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: a_id, b, c (with a_id as a unique key) and I would like to assign a score for each row based on the number in b and c columns. I have created the following:

```
def b_score_function(df):
    if df['b'] <= 0 :
        return 0
    elif df['b'] <= 2 :
        return 0.25
    else: 
        return 1

def c_score_function(df): 
    if df['c'] <= 0 :
        return 0
    elif df['c'] <= 1 :
        return 0.5
    else: 
        return 1
```

Normally, I would use something like this:

```
df['b_score'] = df(b_score, axis = 1)
df['c_score'] = df(c_score, axis = 1)
```

However, the above approach will be too long if I have multiple columns. I would like to know how can I create a loop for the selected columns? I have tried the following:

```
ds_cols = df.columns.difference(['a_id']).to_list() 

for col in ds_cols:
    df[f'{col}_score'] = df.apply(f'{col}_score_function', axis = 1)
```

but it returned with the following error:

```
'b_score_function' is not a valid function for 'DataFrame' object
```

Can anyone please point out what I did wrong?
Also if anyone can suggest how to create a reusable, that would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How many different column-specific functions do you have in your real data?  Is it just two (b/c) or more?

Comment: Have you tried something like this `df['b_score'] = np.where(df.b<=0, 0,np.where(df.b<=2,0.25, 1))` and for the other one `df['c_score'] = np.where(df.c<=0, 0,np.where(df.c<=1,0.5, 1))`

Comment: The problem with using np.where is I need to always rewrite the case. I would like to be able to reuse the function and would prefer to update in one go.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a_id': range(5), 'b': [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 2.0, 2.5], 'c': [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]})

def b_score_function(df):
    if df['b'] <= 0 :
        return 0
    elif df['b'] <= 2 :
        return 0.25
    else: 
        return 1

def c_score_function(df): 
    if df['c'] <= 0 :
        return 0
    elif df['c'] <= 1 :
        return 0.5
    else: 
        return 1


ds_cols = df.columns.difference(['a_id']).to_list() 
for col in ds_cols:
    df[f'{col}_score'] = df.apply(eval(f'{col}_score_function'), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   a_id     b     c  b_score  c_score
0     0  0.00  0.00     0.00      0.0
1     1  0.25  0.25     0.25      0.5
2     2  0.50  0.50     0.25      0.5
3     3  2.00  1.00     0.25      0.5
4     4  2.50  1.50     1.00      1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if there is a way to iterate the score_funs because I have many columns and functions. I looked around but I couldn't seem to find the answer (especially because of the key)

Comment: I updated my answer and hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt is that pandas cannot access your functions from strings with the same name.  For example, you need to pass `df.apply(b_score_function, axis=1)`, and not `df.apply("b_score_function", axis=1)` (note the double quotes).

My first thought would be to link the column names to functions with a dictionary:

```
funcs = {'b' : b_score_function,
         'c' : c_score_function}

for col in ds_cols:
    foo = funcs[col]
    df[f'{col}_score'] = df.apply(foo, axis = 1)
```

Typing out the dictionary `funcs` may be tedious or infeasible depending on how many columns/functions you have.  If that is the case, you may have to find additional ways to automate the creation and access of your column-specific functions.

One somewhat automatic way is to use [`locals()` or `globals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834451/13386979) - these will return dictionaries which have the functions you defined (as well as other things):

```
for col in ds_cols:
    key = f"{col}_score_function"
    foo = locals()[key]
    df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

This code is dependent on the fact that the function for column `"X"` is called `X_score_function()`, but that seems to be met in your example.  It also requires that every column in `ds_cols` will have a corresponding entry in `locals()`.

---

Somewhat confusingly there are some functions which *you can* access by passing a string to `apply`, but these are only the ones that are shortcuts for numpy functions, like `df.apply('sum')` or `df.apply('mean')`.  [Documentation for this appears to be absent](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).  Generally you would want to do `df.sum()` rather than `df.apply('sum')`, but sometimes being able to access the method by the string is convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Yes, I have more than a dozen columns. I will think of a way to improve mine by creating a dictionary

Comment: @Deysiz you could try using `locals()` or `globals()`, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorial way in a single shot, you can use dictionaries to hold the threshold and replacement values, then [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
# example input
df = pd.DataFrame({'b': [-1, 2, 5],
                   'c': [5, -1, 1]})

# dictionaries (one key:value per column)
thresh = {'b': 2, 'c': 1}
repl = {'b': 0.25, 'c': 0.5}

out = pd.DataFrame(
    np.select([df.le(0), df.le(thresh)],
              [0, pd.Series(repl)],
              1),
    columns=list(thresh),
    index=df.index
).add_suffix('_score')
```

output:

```
   b_score  c_score
0     0.00      1.0
1     0.25      0.0
2     1.00      0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting way to do it.